# Recurrence Relations using Maple

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I wanted to know how can one find arbitrary number of terms of the non-linear recurrence (using software, like maple)such as
$$a_{2n-1}=-\sum_{j=1}^{n}{n+j-1\choose 2j-2}a_{n+j-2}, \ a_{0}=-1$$
$$a_{2n}=-\sum_{j=1}^{n}{n+j\choose 2j-1}a_{n+j-1}.$$

I have tried something like the following code into maple, yet it doesn't yield anything useful,

`a := n -> rsolve({a(0) = -1, a(2*n) = -sum(binomial(n + j, 2*j - 1)*a(n + j - 1), j = 1 .. n), a(2*n - 1) = -sum(binomial(n + j - 1, 2*j - 2)*a(n + j - 2), j = 1 .. n)}, a(n), makeproc);`.

**Edit**:I know that there is the Mathematica recurrence table, but don't know how to get it working for this particular example. I have also tried the Rsolve as shown above, it works for some examples like the second-order linear recurrences but not for this one.

The link for recurrence table:-https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Maple's `rsolve` is useful only when there is a closed-form solution.  For your example, I would do this:

```
>restart;

>aa := proc(m)  
option remember;  
local n,s;  
if type(m,even) then  
  n:=m/2;  
  s:=-add(binomial(n+j,2*j-1)*aa(n+j-1),j=1..n);  
else  
  n:=(m+1)/2;  
  s:=-add(binomial(n+j-1,2*j-2)*aa(n+j-2),j=1..n);  
fi;  
s;  
end;  
aa := proc (m) local n, s, j; option remember; if type(m, even) 
   then n := (1/2)*m; s := -add(binomial(n+j, 2*j-1)*aa(n+j-1), 
   j = 1 .. n) else n := (1/2)*m+1/2; s := -add(binomial(n+j-1, 
   2*j-2)*aa(n+j-2), j = 1 .. n) end if; s end proc  

>aa(0):=-1;  
                          aa(0) := -1  
>seq(aa(n),n=0..10);  
     -1, 1, -2, 5, -14, 42, -132, 429, -1430, 4862, -16796
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, just wondering if there is a systematic way where one can learn to code with mathematica?? Especially for recurrences.

Comment: Sorry meant to say Maple instead of Mathematica above.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** @GEdgars result indicates we have here signed *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\qquad\qquad n\geq 0}
\end{align*}

We can write OPs homogeneous linear recurrence relation by shifting indices and putting all terms at one side to get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n+j}{2j}a_{n+j-1}&=0\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{1}\\
\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n+j+1}{2j+1}a_{n+j}&=0\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{2}\\
a_0&=-1
\end{align*}

**Add-on 2022-01-16:** @MarkoRiedel has given an interesting derivation of (2). Here we follow him very closely and show the validity of (1).

We already know that $a_n$ are a signed version of the ubiquituous *[Catalan numbers](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/transparencies/tsuda.pdf)* $C_n=(-1)^{n+1}a_n$, so that (1) becomes
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n+j}{2j}(-1)^{n+j}C_{n+j-1}=0}\tag{1C}
\end{align*}

Denoting with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series we recall a generating function of the $C_n$
\begin{align*}
C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=[z^n]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{3.1}
\end{align*}
We will also often use the representation
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^n\tag{3.2}
\end{align*}
together with *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* expansion and *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion.

> We start with the LHS of (1C) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\binom{n+j}{2j}(-1)^{n+j}C_{n+j-1}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n-j}{2n-2j}(-1)^{j}C_{2n-j-1}\tag{4.1}\\
> &=\sum_{j\geq 0}[w^{2n-2j}](1+w)^{2n-j}(-1)^j[z^{2n-j-1}]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\tag{4.2}\\
> &=[z^{2n-1}]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n}\sum_{j\geq 0}(-1)^j\frac{w^{2j}}{(1+w)^j}z^j\tag{4.3}\\
> &=[z^{2n-1}]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{w^2z}{1+w}}\tag{4.4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[z^{-1}]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z^{2n+1}}[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n+1}\frac{1}{1+w+w^2z}}\tag{4.5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4.1) we change the order of summation $j\to n-j$.
- In (4.2) we apply (3.1) and (3.2). We also set the upper limit of the series to infinity noting that due to the *coefficient of* operator terms with index $j>n$ do not contribute.
- In (4.3) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$ and factor out terms which do not depend on the summation index $j$.
- In (4.4) we make a geometric series expansion.

**Change of variable:** We want to get rid of the square root in (4.5). By writing $[z^{-1}]$ we prepare a variable change using *formal residue* calculus which is formidably described in the classic *[Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-59)* by G. P. Egorychev.

Following @MarkoRiedels derivation we set
\begin{align*}
1-\sqrt{1-4z}=v\qquad\qquad z=\frac{v}{2}\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)\qquad\qquad dz=\frac{1-v}{2}\,dv\tag{$\star$}
\end{align*}

> We continue from (4.5) and obtain using the substitution ($\star$)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^{-1}]}&\color{blue}{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z^{2n+1}}[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n+1}\frac{1}{1+w+w^2z}}\tag{4.5}\\
> &=[v^{-1}]\frac{v\,\frac{1-v}{2}}{2\left(\frac{v}{2}\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)\right)^{2n+1}}[w^{2n}]\frac{(1+w)^{2n+1}}{1+w+w^2\,\frac{v}{2}\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)}\tag{4.6}\\
> &=2^{2n-1}[v^{2n-1}]\frac{1-v}{\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}[w^{2n}]\frac{(1+w)^{2n+1}}{1+w+w^2\,\frac{v}{2}\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)}\tag{4.7}\\
> &\color{blue}{=2^{2n-1}[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n+1}[v^{2n-1}]}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}\left(\frac{-\frac{v}{2}}{1+w\,\frac{v}{2}}
> +\frac{1-\frac{v}{2}}{1+w-w\,\frac{v}{2}}\right)}\tag{4.8}\\
> \end{align*}

**Time to pause and reflect:** In (4.6) and (4.7) we do the variable substitution and some simplifications. It is (4.8) which is a remarkable step done by @MarkoRiedel. This clever split into denominators linear in two variables $v$ and $w$ is the **key** to finish the proof.

We can now show that both terms in the parentheses cancel by showing
\begin{align*}
&2^{2n-1}[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n+1}[v^{2n-1}]\\
&\qquad\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}\left(\frac{-\frac{v}{2}}{1+w\,\frac{v}{2}}
\right)=-\binom{4n-1}{2n}\tag{5}\\
&2^{2n-1}[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n+1}[v^{2n-1}]\\
&\qquad\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}\left(\frac{1-\frac{v}{2}}{1+w-w\,\frac{v}{2}}
\right)=\binom{4n-1}{2n}\tag{6}\\
\end{align*}
from which the claim (1C) follows.

> We start with the left-hand side of (5) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{2^{2n-1}}&\color{blue}{[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n+1}[v^{2n-1}]
> \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}\left(\frac{-\frac{v}{2}}{1+w\,\frac{v}{2}}\right)}\\
> &=-2^{2n-2}[v^{2n-2}]\sum_{q\geq 0}\binom{-2n-1}{q}\left(-\frac{v}{2}\right)^q\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n+1}\sum_{j\geq 0}(-1)^j\left(w\,\frac{v}{2}\right)^j\tag{5.1}\\
> &=-2^{2n-2}[v^{2n-2}]\sum_{q\geq 0}\binom{2n+q}{q}\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)^q
> \sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{2n+1}{2n-j}\left(-\frac{v}{2}\right)^j\tag{5.2}\\
> &=-2^{2n-2}\sum_{q=0}^{2n-2}\binom{2n+q}{q}\frac{1}{2^q}[v^{2n-2-q}]\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{2n+1}{2n-j}
> \left(-\frac{v}{2}\right)^j\tag{5.3}\\
> &=-2^{2n-2}\sum_{q=0}^{2n-2}\binom{2n+q}{q}\frac{1}{2^q}\binom{2n+1}{q+2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-2-q}\tag{5.4}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{2n-2}\binom{2n+q}{2n}\binom{2n+1}{q+2}(-1)^{q+1}\\
> &=-\binom{4n-1}{2n}+\sum_{q=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n+q}{2n}\binom{2n+1}{q+2}(-1)^{q+1}\tag{5.5}\\
> &=-\binom{4n-1}{2n}+\sum_{q=2}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+q-2}{2n}\binom{2n+1}{q+2}(-1)^{q+1}\tag{5.6}\\
> &=-\binom{4n-1}{2n}-[z^{2n}](1+z)^{2n-2}\sum_{q=2}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{q}(-1)^q(1+z)^q\tag{5.7}\\
> &=-\binom{4n-1}{2n}-[z^{2n}](1+z)^{2n-2}\left(1-(1+z)\right)^{2n+1}\tag{5.8}\\
> &=-\binom{4n-1}{2n}+[z^{-1}](1+z)^{2n-2}\tag{5.9}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\binom{4n-1}{2n}}
> \end{align*}
> and (5) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (5.1) we make a binomial and a geometric series expansion.
- In (5.2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ and apply (3.2) from right to left.
- In (5.3) we apply again the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$ and set the upper limit of the outer sum to $2n-2$ since other terms do not contribute.
- In (5.4) we select the coefficient of $v^{2n-2-1}$.
- In (5.5) we add and subtract $\binom{4n-1}{2n}$ by adding $q=2n-1$.
- In (5.6) we shift the index and start with $q=2$.
- In (5.7) we again apply (3.2) from right to left.
- In (5.8) we apply the binomial theorem noting that the terms $q=0$ and $q=1$ do not contribute since we select the coefficient of $z^{2n}$.
- In (5.9) we see the right-hand term is zero.

> Finally we start with the left-hand side of (6) and obtain similarly as above
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{2^{2n-1}}&\color{blue}{[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n+1}[v^{2n-1}]\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}
> \left(\frac{1-\frac{v}{2}}{1+w-w\,\frac{v}{2}}\right)}\\
> &=2^{2n-1}[v^{2n-1}]\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{v}{2}\right)^{2n}}[w^{2n}]\frac{(1+w)^{2n}}{1-\frac{w}{1+w}\,\frac{v}{2}}\\
> &=2^{2n-1}[x^{2n-1}]\sum_{q\geq 0}\binom{-2n}{q}\left(-\frac{v}{2}\right)^q\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot[w^{2n}](1+w)^{2n}\sum_{j\geq 0}\left(\frac{w}{1+w}\right)^j\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)^j\\
> &=2^{2n-1}[v^{2n-1}]\sum_{q\geq 0}\binom{2n+q-1}{q}\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)^q
> \sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{2n-j}{2n-j}\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)^j\\
> &=2^{2n-1}\sum_{q=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1+q}{q}\frac{1}{2^q}[v^{2n-1-q}]\sum_{j\geq 0}\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)^j\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1+q}{q}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1+q}{2n-1}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{2n-1}[z^{2n-1}](1+z)^{2n-1+q}\\
> &=[z^{2n-1}](1+z)^{2n-1}\sum_{q=0}^{2n-1}(1+z)^q\\
> &=[z^{2n-1}](1+z)^{2n-1}\,\frac{(1+z)^{2n}-1}{(1+z)-1}\\
> &=[z^{2n}]\left((1+z)^{4n-1}-(1+z)^{2n-1}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{4n-1}{2n}}
> \end{align*}
> and (6) follows.
>
> We conclude from (5) and (6) the claim (1C) resp. (1) is valid.

Comment: Very nice work.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer 

Comment: @SarthakSahoo: You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Observe that once we have identified  the sequence from the Maple data
as  @epi163sqrt has  done,  we  can prove  the  two recurrences.  With
regular Catalan numbers  $C_n$ the second recurrence is  (we leave the
first one to the reader)

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} {n+j\choose 2j-1} (-1)^{n+j} C_{n+j-1} = 0.$$

The LHS is setting $j$ to $n+1-j$

$$\sum_{j=0}^n {2n+1-j\choose 2n-2j+1} (-1)^{j+1} C_{2n-j}.$$

This is (discarding the sign because we are trying to verify that the
sum is zero):

$$[z^{2n}] \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}
[w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+1} 
\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^{j} \frac{w^{2j}}{(1+w)^j} z^j.$$

Here we have extended the sum to infinity because of the coefficient
extractor in $w$ and obtain

$$[z^{2n}] \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}
[w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{1+w^2z/(1+w)}
\\ = [z^{2n}] \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}
[w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+2} \frac{1}{1+w+w^2z}.$$

The contribution from $z$ is

$$\; \underset{z}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}
\frac{1}{1+w+w^2z}$$

Now put $1-\sqrt{1-4z} = v$ so that $z= v(2-v)/4$ and $dz = (1-v)/2 \; 
dv$ to get

$$\; \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{4^{2n+1}}{v^{2n+1} (2-v)^{2n+1}} \frac{v}{v(2-v)/2}
\frac{(1-v)/2}{1+w+w^2 v(2-v)/4}
\\ = \; \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{4^{2n+1}}{v^{2n+1} (2-v)^{2n+2}}
\frac{1-v}{1+w+w^2 v(2-v)/4}
\\ = 2^{2n} \; \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{v^{2n+1} (1-v/2)^{2n+2}}
\frac{1-v}{1+w+w^2 v(2-v)/4}.$$

Observe that

$$\frac{1-v}{1+w+w^2 v(2-v)/4}
= -\frac{v}{2+vw} + \frac{2-v}{2(1+w)-vw}.$$

The contribution from the first term is

$$2^{2n} \; \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{v^{2n+1} (1-v/2)^{2n+2}}
\left(-\frac{1}{2} v\right)
[w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+2} 
\sum_{q=0}^{2n+1} (-1)^q \frac{1}{2^q} v^q w^q
\\ = - 2^{2n-1}  \; \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{v^{2n} (1-v/2)^{2n+2}}
\sum_{q=0}^{2n+1} {2n+2\choose 2n+1-q} 
(-1)^q \frac{1}{2^q} v^q
\\ = - 2^{2n-1} 
\sum_{q=0}^{2n} {2n+2\choose q+1} 
(-1)^q \frac{1}{2^q} {2n-1-q+2n+1\choose 2n+1}
\frac{1}{2^{2n-1-q}}
\\ = -\sum_{q=0}^{2n} 
{2n+2\choose q+1} (-1)^q {4n-q\choose 2n+1}.$$

The contribution from the second term is

$$2^{2n} \; \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{v^{2n+1} (1-v/2)^{2n+2}}
\left(1-\frac{1}{2} v\right)
[w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+1} 
\sum_{q=0}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{2^q} v^q \frac{w^q}{(1+w)^q}
\\ = 2^{2n} \; \underset{v}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{v^{2n+1} (1-v/2)^{2n+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{2n+1} {2n+1-q\choose 2n+1-q} \frac{1}{2^q} v^q
\\ = 2^{2n} \sum_{q=0}^{2n} \frac{1}{2^q} 
{2n-q+2n\choose 2n} \frac{1}{2^{2n-q}}
= \sum_{q=0}^{2n} {4n-q\choose 2n}.$$

We thus have to show that

$$\sum_{q=0}^{m} {m+2\choose q+1} (-1)^q {2m-q\choose m+1}
= \sum_{q=0}^{m} {2m-q\choose m}.$$

The LHS is

$$\sum_{q=1}^{m+1} {m+2\choose q} (-1)^{q-1} {2m+1-q\choose m+1}
\\ = {2m+1\choose m}
- [z^{m+1}] (1+z)^{2m+1}
\sum_{q=0}^{m+2} {m+2\choose q} \frac{(-1)^q}{(1+z)^q}
\\ = {2m+1\choose m}
- [z^{m+1}] (1+z)^{2m+1}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^{m+2}
\\ = {2m+1\choose m}
- [z^{m+1}] (1+z)^{m-1} z^{m+2} = {2m+1\choose m}.$$

The RHS is

$$\sum_{q=0}^m {2m-q\choose m-q}
= [z^m] (1+z)^{2m} \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^q}{(1+z)^q}
\\ = [z^m] (1+z)^{2m} \frac{1}{1-z/(1+z)}
= [z^m] (1+z)^{2m+1} = {2m+1\choose m}.$$

This concludes the argument.

Comment: A great answer and a pleasure to learn from it. Many thanks for this contribution. (+1)

Comment: Thanks! It might be helpful if you were to do the other recurrence using your methods and notation.

Comment: I've added a proof of the other part appreciating your answer all the more.